# Getting an error when compiling for production more in M2. requirejs-min-resolver.min.js is missing

Tags: magento2

When compiling for production mode I am getting this error:

> The contents from the
> "~/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-min-resol
> ver.min.js" file can't be read.
> Warning!file_get_contents(~/pub/static/adminhtml/Magent
> o/backend/en_US/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js): failed to open stream:
> No such file or directory

We are using Amasty Page Speed Optimizer but this also happens with standard M2 js minification and bundling.

Comment: flush cache and try using 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US.

Comment: Same error. Flushed cache, reset permissions, re-deployed.